# How do you remove a SPECIFIC level of potion effect from a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm creating a Minecraft map which requires you to find splash potions to access new areas. I'm using `effect @p clear minecraft:speed 0`, but it sometimes activates another potion's ability. How do I stop this from happening?

I'm asking how to remove a specific level of potion effect.

**Example:**

Speed 5 triggers a `tp` command to teleport me to underground (desired), but this also happens when I use Speed 1 (undesired)

Comment: Well if we were to be all classic here you could just tell the player to drink a milk bucket manually... But the command you use is correct, at least according to the wiki. However, it is possible that you are triggering other commands / or other command blocks at the same time that is causing a new potion affect. Could you please describe which potion and maybe I can troubleshoot this more. Otherwise above is the best advice I can give you.

Comment: eg:i use speed 5 to trigger a tp command to teleport me to underground but this also happens when i use speed 1 How do i stop THIS from happening

Comment: If your still having trouble with this would you post the actual commands you are using?

Answer (score 1):

When you apply the effect to the player, set some scoreboard value to 1. Set it back to 0 when clearing the effect from the player. This way you can keep track of what effects the player might or might not have.

To create a scoreboard do `scoreboard objectives create speed1 dummy`. Then set the player's score to 1 using `scoreboard players set <player> speed1 1`. After that give all players with a score of 1 speed using `effect @a[score_speed1_min=1] speed 1000000 <whatever value> true`. When clearing the effect do the exact opposite, set the score back to 0 and clear the effects of all players with a score of 1.

You should have the command blocks applying and clearing the effects on a clock. If you set score speed2 for player1 to 0, while a player2 has speed1 set to 1, this will happen:

1. Speed (all levels) will get cleared from player1 and player2
2. Speed 1 will be given to player2

So:
Before - Player1 has speed 2, player2 has speed 1.
After - Player1 has no speed, player2 still has speed 1

Please excuse me for my possibly not very good English, I hope this helped you :)